# Global action layout editor - not able to set fields in columns

Tags: community, salesforcedx

I am looking to have the 2 columns inside of the layout of a global action. Is that even possible? I tried this, but the actual layout it shows up as one column.
[image]

[image]

Comment: do you have a screenshot of where you're using the global action and how it appears? I have no issues showing 2 columns in a global action but I may not be replicating your scenario.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves I have added it to the original post.

Comment: AssignedTo was added just for testing purposes, but that was added to the column underneath Activity_type.

Comment: is this specifically in a "community" or have you tested with global actions within your internal org?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to put some other field instead of Activity Type (it seems this field read only). So you will not be able to see it when you file Global action.

Comment: I tried, still all fields show up vertically.